# Apply a function to each element of a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 480x640 sized matrix(Lets say `A`). And I want another matrix (`B`) of the same size where each element in `B` is the `exp()` of that corresponding element in `A`.
Is there an elegant way of dong this apart from a regular for loop ?

Answer (score 8):

`exp` is a [vectorized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming) operation:

```
B = exp(A);
```

It doesn't go much more elegant than this ;)

Note that most operations in Matlab are vectorized by default thus you do not need to explicitly loop through all the elements of the matrix.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of good MATLAB practice it's almost always best to attempt to utilize vectorized operations that are built into MATLAB, as [Shai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33546626/2748311) speaks to.

However, to answer the explicit question, functions like [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html), [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), and [`structfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/structfun.html). These functions can apply a function to each element of an array, cell array, and structure, respectively. This is useful for cases where there is no built-in for what you want to do or it is not a vectorized operation.

For example, with `arrayfun`:

```
A = [1, 2; 3, 4];
B = arrayfun(@(x) exp(x), A);
C = exp(A);

test = all(B(:) == C(:)) % Test for equivalence
```

And `test` returns `true`.

Comment: For the avoidance of confusion it's worth mentioning that you don't *have* to use an anonymous function with `arrayfun`! `arrayfun(@exp, A)` is fine.

Comment: you forgot `spfun`. @Will try and think what will happen if you `spfun(@exp, S)` vs `exp(S)` ;)